# How to pass an object to another activity and reference it in other methods

Tags: java, android, object, android-activity

I am trying to pass an object from one activity to another. But from the methods I've seen, it seems like you always grab that object in the onCreate method, which makes sense. But since onCreate is protected, I'm unable to reference that object in other methods in that activity.

Is there a better way to do this? I'm still getting the hang of all this Android stuff.

Comment: [Shared Preferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html). Use it in any method.

Comment: You can use intent to pass the objects, access them in oncreate make those variables class level global, so you can access them or use shared preference or if this object is frequently needed by many activities then , you can create a pojo of such object

Comment: Those both seem like good solutions. I will try both and let y'all know

Answer (score 0):

use intent for this that is the best way for doing this:-

```
 intent=new Intent(this,yourotheractivty.class);
  intent.putExtra("object",object);
  startActivity(intent);
```

get this in your activity's oncreate using the get intent if you are creating a custom object you better use parceable

Answer (score 0):

Using an `Intent` is one common method of sending an Object around, but it sounds to me like you are looking for something like a generalized observer pattern.

I would create class that holds references to subscriber objects and what callbacks they would like receive. Upon sending a callback and associated data to that class, have the subscriber objects registered to that callback receive the associated data.

Existing solutions:
If you're using `Guava` it has one built in (https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/EventBusExplained), otherwise take a look at Otto (http://square.github.io/otto/) or EventBus (https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus).